# Facebook Canvas: redirect_uri is not owned by the application

Tags: javascript, facebook, localhost, facebook-canvas

I am trying to integrate facebook canvas on my web application that is currently running on `localhost:8080`
upon running the site it gave me this error.

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

And here is my app settings.

[image]

I was just following the documentation and this error showed up,

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                            FB
                                    .init({
                                        appId : 'myappIdHere', // App ID
                                        channelUrl : 'https://apps.facebook.com/mytestapp/', // Channel File
                                        status : true, // check login status
                                        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                                        xfbml : true
                                    // parse XFBML
                                    });
                            FB.ui({
                                method : 'feed'
                            });
                        };
                        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
                        (function(d, s, id) {
                            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                                return;
                            }
                            js = d.createElement(s);
                            js.id = id;
                            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: when do you get that error? When you are saving your app settings? or trying to add the app to a page tab?

Comment: I am trying to do "Post to on wall".

Comment: could you post your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL you need to place in "canvas url" is probably localhost:8080 (the app url is determined by "name space", and will always be http://apps.facebook.com/namespace (this has to be unique for your app.)

You need to specify a redirect URI for 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

```
<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      redirect_uri: 'https://apps.facebook.com/mytestapp/',
      link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/mytestapp/',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>
```