# Facebook API Error Code: 191 with specified url

Tags: facebook

I've found some questions about this mistake, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858662/facebook-canvas-redirect-uri-is-not-owned-by-the-application) for example.
I made changes according to them. I've added my url  as site in my app on facebook which has domain name the same called as my site. Now I use this func on click on share link of my site:

```
    var url = 'http://callbackyou.ru/';
    var title = 'kkkkkk';
    var description = 'description';
    var image = 'http://callbackyou.ru/img/callbackyou.ru.jpg';
function fb_share()
{
    FB.init({
      appId : '***',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.5'
    });
    FB.ui( {
        method: 'feed',
        redirect_uri: 'https://callbackyou.ru/',
        name: title,
        link: url,
        picture: image,
        caption: description
    }, function( response ) {
        if ( response !== null && typeof response.post_id !== 'undefined' ) {
            call_soc();
        }
    } );
}
```

And this doesn't work I get mistake:

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

Comment: Why are you even using that parameter there at all? It is not necessary when dialogs are called via `FB.ui` – so just remove it.

Comment: I added redirect uri because I thought that it will help. It gives me mistake anyway=(